# Print name two times in horizontal

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to print name two times but in horizontal format.

**Expected Output :**

Gab
Gab

**Output:**

G
a
b
G
a
b

**My Code :**

```
name = "Gab"

total = name * 2

for gen in total:
    print(gen)
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply `print(total)` ?  (or `print(name * 2)`)

Answer (score 0):

`total` should just be `2`, and you should use `range` (or any other method to generate an iterable of size `total`):

```
name = input("Enter name: ")

total = 2

for gen in range(total):
    print(name)
```

##### how your code failed

```
name = "Gab"

total = name * 2  # total is now "GabGab"

for letter in total: # now we iterate over the letters of "GabGab"
    print(letter)    # and print them on separated lines
```